# How to avoid "Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, exception, response.redirect

I'm cleaning up some legacy framework code and a huge amount of it is simply coding by exception.  No values are checked to see if they are null, and as a result, copious amounts of exceptions are thrown and caught.

I've got most of them cleaned up, however, There are a few error / login / security related framework methods that are doing Response.Redirect and now that we are using ajax, we are getting ALOT of **"Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback."**  And I'd like to avoid this if at all possible.

Is there a way to programatically avoid this exception?  I'm looking for something like

```
if (Request.CanRedirect)
    Request.Redirect("url");
```

Note, this is also happening with Server.Transfer, so I'd like to be able to check if I am able to do Request.Redirect OR Server.Transfer.

Currently, its simply doing this

```
try
{
    Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx"); // sometimes response.redirect
}
catch (Exception abc)
{
    // handle error here, the error is typically:
    //    Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try

```
if (!Page.IsCallback)
    Request.Redirect("url");
```

or if you dont have a Page handy...

```
try
{
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        return;
    if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler == null)
        return;
    if (!(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is System.Web.UI.Page))
        return;
    if (((System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).IsCallback)
        return;

    Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx");
}
catch (Exception abc)
{
    // handle it
}
```

Comment: Where in HttpContext.Current can I find IsCallback?  I wont always have a Page

Comment: Ah, found it, I added the code I ended up using to your answer, since your snippet is really all I needed.  I can't believe I didn't think of something so simple myself, heh.  Thanks man

Answer (score 9):

I believe you can simply replace `Server.Transfer()` with `Response.RedirectLocation()` which works during callback.

```
try
{
    Response.RedirectLocation("~/Error.aspx"); // sometimes response.redirect
}
catch (Exception abc)
{
    // handle error here, the error is typically:
    //    Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback
}
```

Comment: For the record, I find (ASP.NET 4.x) that a) `Response.RedirectLocation` is a property not a method, and b) it does not expand the `~` notation, so you need `Response.RedirectLocation = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Error.aspx")`.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned above, but expanded to include the **.NET 4.x version** and assigning to the `Response.RedirectLocation` property when there is no `Page` available.

```
try 
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
}
catch (ApplicationException) 
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation =    
                         System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Error.aspx");
}
```

Comment: It really works. Thanks a lot, You solved my big problem

Answer (score 1):

You should load up your ScriptManager or ScriptManagerProxy, and then check the IsInAsyncPostBack flag. That would look something like this:

```
ScriptManager sm = this.Page.Form.FindControl("myScriptManager") as ScriptManager;
if(!sm.IsInAsyncPostBack)
{
    ...
}
```

By doing this, you can mix async postbacks (which should fail to redirect) with normal postbacks, which I'm assuming you still want to redirect.

Comment: hrm, could you elaborate what the difference is between that and Page.IsCallback?

Comment: It looks like the difference is that IsCallback works for the Asp.net ICallbackEventHandler interface, while IsInAsyncPostBack works for UpdatePanel based changes.

This is the most direct comparison between them I could find:

http://timstall.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/avoiding_unnecessary_server_work_in_aspnet.htm

Comment: You can also use ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

Answer (score 0):

Add this line instead of `response.redirect` if you are getting error using `Dev express`

```
DevExpress.Web.ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback("~/Login.aspx");
```