# Response Redirect cannot be called in Page callback?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, devexpress

I am getting the following error when I leave my web inactive for a while

"Response.Redirect.cannot be called in a Page callback."

I'm storing the user ids in session and during page load I check
to see if the user id exists if not then I redirect them to the login page.

I am using devexpress controls, How can I get the redirect to work?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538749/how-to-avoid-response-redirect-cannot-be-called-in-a-page-callback

Comment: @Lucas - I don't think so. That questioner just wanted to stop the error and was happy with using `if (!Page.IsCallback)` I think @Kyle wants some way to redirect the user to the login page if their session has expired.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the `Response.RedirectLocation` property instead which works during callback.

[HttpResponse.RedirectLocation Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectlocation.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

if (Page.IsCallback)
        ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback("~/Login.aspx");

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesASPxWebControl_RedirectOnCallbacktopic

Answer (score 2):

You can usually turn callbacks off for devexpress controls like the ASPxGridView using the "EnableCallbacks" property. This will obviously cause the controls to use postbacks, but it will also allow Response.Redirect to do its job.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpResponse.RedirectLocation` Property on MSDN works for me in same problem

here is the sample code from [Msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirectlocation?view=netframework-4.8)

```
Response.StatusCode = 301;
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.RedirectLocation = "http://www.newurl.com ";
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the redirect to work in a callback.  Perhaps instead of doing Response.Redirect on the server you could write some value in a `<script type="text/javascript"/>` block and set the window.location.href (redirect) on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
string TARGET_URL = ...;
if(Page.IsCallback)
    DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback(TARGET_URL);
else
    Response.Redirect(TARGET_URL);
```

Refer at [KA18851](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18851) in Devexpress

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it is impossible to use the Response.Redirect during a callback.  Please refer to the 
following blog post in this regard.

http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2008/08/25/how-to-redirect-to-login-page-after-session-timeout.aspx