# Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error. I am using ICallbackEventHandler to fill the some dropdowns. On a particular condition I want to redirect to a certain aspc page but I am getting

> Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback.

I have also used Server.Transfer but problem did not solve.

Comment: hmmmm.. ok. Where is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate: **[How to avoid “Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538749/how-to-avoid-response-redirect-cannot-be-called-in-a-page-callback)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response.Redirect() implicate call the `Response.End()` which would absolutely stop the page-lifecycle execution.

So you cannt use it in your callback method. You can use a client method instead it like `window.location.href = "...."`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have used

Comment: Thanks for your response but I tried following also
string strSessiontimoutUrl = string.Concat(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Scheme, "://", HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["POINT_SESSION_TIMEOUT_URL"]);

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Redirect",
                                               "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location.href='" +
                                               strSessiontimoutUrl + "'; </script>", false);

but it did not work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I just used this and worked. It was a great idea!